# Basic jQuery Slider - Current Slide Number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently having issues displaying the current slide number, basically I need to have the current slides number inserted into a span class called current slide. I'm using follow jquery slider: http://basic-slider.com

I'm using this snippet to call the script.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      var total = jQuery('.bjqs li').length;

      $('#banner-slide').bjqs({
        animtype      : 'slide',
        height        : 490,
        width         : 695,
        showmarkers   : false,
        responsive    : false

      });

      jQuery('#slider-status > .total-slides').html(total);


    });
```

According to the design it needs to be shown as 1(current slide) / 3(being total amount)

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using bjqs min file you can modify `set_next function` to get current slide number and apped it to span.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#banner-slide').bjqs({
    animtype      : 'slide',
    height        : 490,
    width         : 695,
    showmarkers   : true, // set it to true
    responsive    : false

});
```

From http://basic-slider.com/

```
showmarkers : true, // Show individual slide markers
```

Comment: That shows the number scrolling through 1 through how many slides in a sorted list. According to the design it needs to be shown as 1(current slide) / 3(being total amount).

Comment: Then you can change the `function` `var conf_markers = function() {` on https://github.com/jcobb/basic-jquery-slider/blob/master/js/bjqs-1.3.js like: 
`var marker = $('<li><a href="#">'+ state.currentslide +'</a></li>');marker.addClass('active-marker'); marker.appendTo($m_wrapper);` this will give you a `single current slide number`

Comment: Cool thanks for the help it really pointed me in the right direction. Quick problem, when I use appendTo it starts listing out the slides instead of replacing the last number.