# jQuery count up to a target number + counting elements in a div

Tags: jquery, image, count, slider, counting

I'm using a slider called superslides. I'm trying to display current slide and number of slides which auto decrements and increments when next and prev is clicked. So far i have the following code;

```
var totalItems = $('.slides-container img').length;
  var currentIndex = $('div.slide-active').index() + 1;
  $('.num').html(''+currentIndex+'/'+totalItems+'');
  $('#multiple-slides').superslides({
    hashchange: false,
    pagination: false,
    animation: 'fade',
    play: 4000,
  });  
  $('#multiple-slides').bind('animated.slides', function() {
      currentIndex = $('div.slide-active').index() + 1;
     $('.num').html(''+currentIndex+'/'+totalItems+'');
  });
```

I think this will work, if only i could apply an active class (.slide-active in my case) to the active slide.

Example - http://www.smallbone.co.uk/collections/kitchens/macassar (See right slide arrow)

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355903/basic-jquery-slider-current-slide-number).

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable for the current slide. Do something like:

```
var sliderLength = $('.slides-container img').length;
var currentSlide = 1;
```

then you'll probably have a next slide and a previous slide function. I dunno. And you'd just increment/decrement the value of `currentSlide` in the respective function e.g.

```
function nextSlide() {
     // Do some stuff
     currentSlide++;
}
```

and

```
function prevSlide() {
     // Do some stuff
     currentSlide--;
}
```

Then you can update the DOM with the new current slide with something as simple as

```
$(".current-slide").html("<p>" + currentSlide + "/" + sliderLength + "</p>");
```

or whatever..

Comment: Sorry updated my question due to more research, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 var g = document.getElementById('my_div');
for (var i = 0, len = g.children.length; i < len; i++)
{

    (function(index){
        g.children[i].onclick = function(){
              alert(index + "/7")  ;
        }    
    })(i);

}
```

check the link : http://jsfiddle.net/PgEcn/4/